# Remove the Toolbar in GVim

Tags: vim, toolbar

How do I remove the Toolbar (which has the open save buttons) in GVim?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the menu/tool bar of gvim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525518/how-to-hide-the-menu-tool-bar-of-gvim)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
:set guioptions-=T
```

See also:

```
:help 'guioptions'
```

Comment: After viewing the link provided by _a paid nerd_, I added it to $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim (on windows)

Comment: set guioptions=0 (to remove all)

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to use the -= operator (as shown in the [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846884/5742) by [@a paid nerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102704/a-paid-nerd)). Add this line to the configuration file (`$MYVIMRC`)

```
:set guioptions-=T
```

In order to find out what the above line does (see below), besides issuing a help command, you can also find it [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'guioptions').

---

I have my .vimrc set as follows

```
set guioptions=aegimrLt
```

where the definition for each of the options can be found by issuing

```
:help guioptions
```

Comment: It appears `:help guioptions` recommends `set guioptions+=` and `set guioptions-=` rather than `set guioptions=`, in case some new options are added in the future..

Comment: yes indeed, just realized this recently when I revisited my config for neovim. These are one of those things where you just set up and forget LOL

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
:set toolbar=
:help 'toolbar'
```

Comment: But `:help 'toolbar'` itself contradicts your first line: "If none of the strings specified in 'toolbar' are valid or if 'toolbar' is empty, this option is ignored.  If you want to disable the toolbar, you need to set the 'guioptions' option.  "