# How to hide the menu/tool bar of gvim?

Tags: vim

I don't have use for the menu and tools bars in gvim on Windows; Can I hide them?

This will give more space to the text area.

[image]

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use the [**guioptions**](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27guioptions%27) setting (abbreviated as **go**).

```
:set guioptions -=m
```

Removes the [menu bar](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27go-m%27).

```
:set guioptions -=T
```

Removes the [toolbar](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27go-T%27).

[My reference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hide_toolbar_or_menus_to_see_more_text)

Comment: Abbreviation for `guioptions` is `go`, so `:set go+=m` works also.

Answer (score 66):

you can hide it by typing these command in your .vimrc

```
set guioptions-=m  "menu bar
set guioptions-=T  "toolbar
set guioptions-=r  "scrollbar
```

Answer (score 24):

I have the following code in my `.vimrc` : by default the bar is hidden, but if I want to display it I can use <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle between the two modes.

```
function! ToggleGUICruft()
  if &guioptions=='i'
    exec('set guioptions=imTrL')
  else
    exec('set guioptions=i')
  endif
endfunction

map <F11> <Esc>:call ToggleGUICruft()<cr>

" by default, hide gui menus
set guioptions=i
```

Removing `mTrl` hides the window menu bar, task bar and right scroll bar, it is kind of a Gvim fullscreen mode. See `:help guioptions` for more information and customization.

PS : it is important to keep `i` in your guioptions, otherwise the Vim Icon is not displayed in <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> and task bar.

Comment: Since this might be invoked relatively rarely, another option is to put it into the (right-click) context menu, which would be a [simple change](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3255/2334#how-to-add-an-item-to-vim-context-menu) to the `map <F11>` line.

Answer (score 5):

You can select Edit -> Global settings -> Toggle toolbar. This hides toolbar until you restart VIM. Then, enter `:set`. Vim prompt you list of different options, find line containing `guioptions`. This is what you need to add to .vimrc file to sustain this appearance.

This method can be used if you don't know option name but know how to change it through main menu.

Comment: Weird, `guioptions -m` stopped working, but this worked. Upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I have

```
set guioptions=
```

in my .vimrc. But too often I wanted to use the menu momentarily with `:set go+=m` and `:set go-=m`.

From [Hide toolbar or menus to see more text - Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hide_toolbar_or_menus_to_see_more_text), I use their

```
let mapleader=","
nnoremap <leader>m :if &go=~#'m'<Bar>set go-=m<Bar>else<Bar>set go+=m<Bar>endif<CR>
```

to toggle menu on and off with `,m`. (Well, they actually have `ctrl-F1` as the key-binding.)

For instance, when I need to remember the way to paste from OS' clipboard, I can find it in the menu very quickly. Once found, I'll still type it manually with `"+gP` to build muscle memory, but still I use it so seldom that I forget it too quickly.

Comment: I had `set guioptions=` for a while but this actually caused a problem when pasting from the system clipboard in Ubuntu Gvim. I have `set clipboard=unnamed` in my vimrc so I can paste the system clipboard using `p`

Comment: how do you delete till next occurrence of a character (but opposite direction) you previously searched for with `t`/`T` or `f`/`F` if `,` is mapped to `<leader>`? Blasphemy!

Answer (score 2):

```
set go=c
```

> Use console dialogs instead of popup dialogs for simple choices.

I think this will turn it off, not just hiding it.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27go-c%27

Edit: Just to clarify, this turning off the menus and toolbars in a GUI as well.

[image]

Comment: The question asked about menus and toolbars, not popup dialogs.

Comment: This turning them off as well. This command is the nearest for a console like experience in gvim.

Answer (score 1):

The gVim shipping with Fedora (not sure if other distributions are effected) has a bug that doesn't allow you to remove the menu with `set go-=m`; for some reason, the "m" option isn't in the "go" string until you set it. So the .vimrc command sequence that removes the menu bar on startup in Fedora (tested in 26) is:

```
set go=agitm
set go-=m
```

I couln't find a solution anywhere else, so hopefully that helps someone else using gVim on Fedora.