# GVim - How to hide / "undecorate" the top bar by default?

Tags: vim

If we look at this post: [How to hide the menu/tool bar of gvim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525518/how-to-hide-the-menu-tool-bar-of-gvim) it shows us how to hide the menu and toolbar. What I want to do is to be able to hide the bar on the top (the bar which has the current files name on it - in the post I linked to, the bar says 'sponsor.txt' on it) by default when opening up Gvim. To do it manually, I have to right click the bar and click "Undecorate". Is there anyway for me to add an option on my .vimrc file which allows me to undecorate / hide it by default?

Comment: This is a feature of your window manager/desktop environment. Not Vim's.

Comment: So, what OS and window manager/desktop environment are you using?