# How to hide the menu/tool bar of mvim?

Tags: macos, macvim

## Clarification:

`mvim` stands for `MacVim`, and I got it installed through "home-brew".

## The problem:

Unlike on the Windows equivalent (Gvim), setting option `set guioptions-=m` does not get the menu bar removed on my MacBook Air. (Running latest OS update, of version: 10.12.6).

- Ref: [How to hide the menu/tool bar of gvim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525518/how-to-hide-the-menu-tool-bar-of-gvim)

To be more precise, as I have loaded a lot of plug-ins to my MacVim, the "menu bar" (or, whatever it is called in Mac OS) becomes very crowded, and thereby squeezing all the useful functionalities of the "menu bar".

- The useful "menu bar":[image]
- The not that useful "menu bar", when I am in MacVim: [image]

## Tentative solutions:

1. A 'vim' solution: can I stop those menu-items from being generated in the first place?
2. A 'mac" solution: can I require that the number of useful icon (in the menu bar) to be displayed?